# In what condition i should use topological sort using bfs and topological using dfs?

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, topological-sort

both topological sorting using bfs and dfs has same time complexity

ie O(V+E) where V => number of vertices and E => number of edges

but the question is which algo to use in what condition????

Comment: You can't do a topological sort with BFS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523839/topological-sort-kahns-algorithm-bfs-or-dfs/69527879#69527879

Answer (score 1):

With a breadth first sort you would have the closest nodes to the root in positions closer to the beginning. But with a depth first sort, the ordering would not correspond with the closeness to the root, but with whole or partial paths, one after another. So:

- You would require **BFS,** (Breadth First Sort) for example, to perform an inundation algorithm where you need the nodes of each depth level to be all processed before the ones in the next level. One case: to build network maps.
- On the other hand, **DFS** (Depth First Sort) is used to process dependencies, where you must process a full path of nodes before processing any other path. Compile systems or job schedulers benefit from this kind of sort.

Comment: As an answer to the question about topological sorting, this answer suggest that BFS is a topological sorting technique, which it is not.

Comment: Wikipedia describes an approach to topological sorting based on BFS

Comment: The words "breadth" and "bfs" do not appear in the wikipedia article on topological sorting.

Comment: Oops, it's true